# How to turn wireless and bluetooth on without FN key

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

I own an old MSI x340 which I plan to use it as a media center.
The keyboard does not work anymore so I can't turn the radio signal on (`FN +F8` and `FN+ F9`)
Device manager shows `Intel 5100` Wireless Card and bluetooth as properly installed.
RFKILL shows both hard blocked and they do not respond to `RKILL UNBLOCK`.

Here's what a already tried:

- Update drivers
- External USB keyboard with FN option
- Virtual Keyboard on windows and linux
- MSI S-BAR software for windows
- rfkill unblock all and unblock 1 and 2
- BIOS: does not show any option for build-in hardware enabling or BIOS update on website

I pretty much out of options. 
Any ideias?

Thanks so much for the time.

Alex

Comment: Just a question, have you tried ifup wlan0 command? It is supposed to bring the network interfaces up

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a virtual machine, so I dunno about the wireless. But for bluetooth, there should be a bluetooth symbol in the top right corner of the screen, near the clock. You can click that, and it'll open a small window with options for enabling/disabling bluetooth, as well as making your device discoverable/undiscoverable.

Comment: Yes, I manage to make blueooth work but the most important of all, wi-fi, is still hard blocked. It's impossible to enable it just by clicking in the top corner, it just shows WI-FI BLOCKED BY HARDWARE. Any ideas? Thank you for you time!

Comment: @user304398 Can you check your virtual machine settings? If you're on virtualbox, click on the network icon. If you're on VMware, then stay in the hardware tab. If you look at the list under `Devices` you should see one that says `Network Adaptor`. What does it say to the right of that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not stop suffering and buy a new keyboard? You can buy it at in average $10, actually I can see price 7,8,9,13,18 at these couple of links [**1**](http://www.aliexpress.com/msi-x340-keyboard_price.html) and [**2**](http://www.alibaba.com/showroom/for-msi-x340-laptop-keyboard.html).

And here is [**disassembly**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWdbUCOjVC0) and keyboard replacement instructions.

Comment: This is not even an answer...